# Laravel temporary signed route not verifying correctly with domain

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working with one of my Laravel 8 projects, it's set up as an API on a sub-domain of my website and prefixed with `api.`.

Requests are made to my API on routes like the following: https://api.example.com/api/some-route, and the front-end of the website is on the standard https://example.com/, both of which live on the same server.

I'm trying to get the `URL::temporarySignedRoute` to correctly verify and haven't been able to figure this out properly for weeks now.

My front-end requires a user to verify their email, so they click a button and a Laravel Job is dispatched, and a URL is generated:

```php
/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $team = isset($this->emailData['team_name']) ? $this->emailData['team_name'] : '';

    // programatically set URL to be the api since APP_URL is https://example.com/
    config(['app.url' => 'https://api.example.com//']);

    // 4 hours until expiry, and secure URL
    $verifyURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
      'contact.verify', Carbon::now()->addHours(24), ['contact' => $notifiable['id'], 'team' => $team]
    );

    $data = [
      'team_name' => $team,
      'first_name' => $notifiable['first_name'],
      'url' => $verifyURL
    ];

    try {
        $this->createHistoryEntry('mail', 'Verify Contact', $data, $notifiable);
    } catch (\Exception $e) { }

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Verify Email Address')
                ->markdown('emails.contacts.verify', $data);

}
```

The route looks like:

```php
Route::get('email/contact/verify', 'VerifyContactsController@verifyContact')->name('contact.verify');
```

And when the user receives the email, the URL in the email is something like:

> https://example.com/api/email/contact/verify?contact=1396&expires=1625170384&team=john&signature=0efb448717f4e2d343693bedb2492503f16220790b8d47cc717edc5b505c2cb2

Now, for a starter, I need that URL to be the API, not the front-end, so why isn't the URL getting set to be the API despite setting my config?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I maybe late but you could pass `false` to `temporarySignedRoute` absolute route:

```php
$verifyURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
      'contact.verify', Carbon::now()->addHours(24), ['contact' => $notifiable['id'], 'team' => $team], false);
```

And then append your domain:

```php
[..]

$verifyURL = "https://api.example.com" . $verifyURL;
```

Also, you must set absolute to false where ever you call `hasValidSignature`:

```php
$request->hasValidSignature(false);
```